# How to know if a topic is related to my discipline?

Tags: publications, research-topic

Sometimes detecting that a topic is related to your discipline or not is confusing.

On which factor you know that a work is in your discipline or not.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer here. We won't answer it about your specific research problem (see "Can I ask about my specific situation" in the [help/on-topic]) and its impossible to answer generally, because the approach is different for every research problem. You really should find a mentor who can help you out on a more personal level with your research.

Comment: @ff524 not specific, not general, I wonder then what you do. however I agree and try to modify it.

Comment: I'm not saying you should change it. I'm saying that this is a question that can't be answered on this site, no matter how you rephrase it. This is a great site for many questions about academia, but some questions just can't be answered properly here.

Comment: @ff524 To me the answer is not that hard, for example the single answer actually says it "*Discover what you do, if what you do is the result of what you have learned in your discipline and provide a solution for some problems of the work, then it is related.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit complicated. But here is my take on it:

- For your fake example, it depends of what you do in such a project. Do you design the survey about unemployment? Do you design the website? Is the experiment about the decrease of validity of statistical data? To answer that, ask yourself what are you doing. If you do everything, ask yourself what comes out of the work. Here for example, it looks like a sociological experiment.
- It's only related to Computer science because there is a website, and automation of data collection. But that's pretty much it.
- If your architecture is novel, yes (for a research paper I mean). Otherwise, it is just a technical solution. I will say it again, but it **is** related to the field of computer science because of the technical nature of the solution.
- I don't understand the last question.

In general, ask yourself the right questions about what exactly you do, and what does it brings, what challenges does it face, what solutions does it provide.

Comment: Thank you, the 4th question was "What would you do if you were me" however I merged it with the second question. I would like to know your examples and approaches when you select to work on an application.

Comment: Your point about "a solution for data collection" seems promising, however still I am not sure it is in my field. I develop the site but maybe not the survey, but I could be the first one who suggest such architecture for gathering information on unemployment.

Comment: It's hard without knowing the specifics, and without knowing why you want so bad to categorize your work in such a narrow way. It is perfectly acceptable to work in several field at the same time.
However you are attached to a "main field" usually.

If you only design the computer architecture to handle what you describe, then i would say it's computer science. But don't take my word for it, you know best ;)

Comment: @Buld yes the design could be computer science, but is it something to present? it could be a usual application of it. Then you mean just to forget it. I insisted on it, cause I have limited time to increase my papers :)!

Comment: That's something only you know.